# Convert output of Request `.text()` method to Blob equivalent

Tags: javascript, typescript

We're using an OpenAPI API client generator ([openapi-typescript-codegen](https://github.com/ferdikoomen/openapi-typescript-codegen)) for Typescript, which unfortunately has an issue when handling non-text responses. The library itself seems unmaintained, [as a PR for this issue](https://github.com/ferdikoomen/openapi-typescript-codegen/pull/986) is open since 2022. Our mid term goal is to replace the library, but short term we need a different solution. So far, we've manually changed the offending code, but that gets overridden every time we re-generate the API client, so I'm looking for a different solution.

The problematic code in the library is this function which is being generated:

```js
export const getResponseBody = async (response: Response): Promise<any> => {
  if (response.status !== 204) {
    try {
      const contentType = response.headers.get('Content-Type');
      if (contentType) {
        const jsonTypes = ['application/json', 'application/problem+json'];
        const isJSON = jsonTypes.some((type) => contentType.toLowerCase().startsWith(type));
        if (isJSON) {
          return await response.json();
        } else {
          return await response.text();
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  return undefined;
};
```

Basically, it returns JSON as JSON and everything else as string (using the `text()`) method. In some cases, we're returning binary data through the API, for example images (`application/png`) or PDF files (`application/pdf`).

My question is how to convert the result we get from the `text()` method to the equivalent of calling the `blob()` method? Simply using the Blob constructor like this doesn't give us a functional file:

```
const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
```

Comment: I doubt you can (or should), as when the binary data contains invalid escape sequences they likely got mangled. I would rather try to automate the "*we've manually changed the offending code*" part, by doing some search-and-replace after invoking the codegen